# Регулярное выражение - поиск фамилии и инициалов с точками (только русских)

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения

Помогите пожалуйста составить регулярное выражение для поиска фамилии и инициалов, например: Иванов И. И.
Всё, что я смог сделать, так это вот это:

```
[a-zA-Z. ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

наверно так

```
[А-Я][а-я]+\s+[А-Я]\.\s+[А-Я]\.
```

разбивка по частям

```
[А-Я]      # первая буква должна быть заглавной
[а-я]+     # и хотя бы ещё одна прописная
\s+        # хотя бы один пробел между фамилией и именем
[А-Я]      # одна буква имени
\.         # и точка за ней
\s+[А-Я]\. # аналогично для отчества
```

Логично, что возможно Вам больше подойдет что то вида

```
[А-Я][а-я]{1,20}\s[А-Я]\.[А-Я]\.
```

если записано так `Иванов И.И.`

В некоторых случаях фамилии бывают двойные, через черточку, тогда чуточку улучшим

```
[А-Я][а-я]+-[А-Я][а-я]+\s+[А-Я]\.\s+[А-Я]\.
```

И, возможно, придется подумать о правильной поддержке кириллицы в том языке программирования, который Вы используете.

Comment: Почему то не работает (изменил на англ)

    std::regex exp("[A-Z][a-z]{1,20}\s[A-Z]\.[A-Z]\.");
    std::cout<<regex_match("Marty I. I.", exp);

Вот такой код выводит 0

Comment: логично. Между инициалами пробелы есть, а в регулярке нет. Так что определитесь. В регулярке пробелы добавляются с помощью \s.

Да, так как у Вас с++ - главное правильно слешей добавить.

Comment: @devnikor, пробел между

     I. I.

в регэксп

     [A-Z]\.[A-Z]\.

не вписывается

Comment: А где и сколько слешей добавить не подскажете?

Comment: @devnikor, IMHO @KoVadim Вам все расписал в деталях и regexp

     [А-Я][а-я]+-[А-Я][а-я]+\s+[А-Я]\.\s+[А-Я]\.

с пробелами между именем и отчеством (правда для фамилий типа *Петров-Водкин*) привел.

А насчет слэшей (точнее бэкслешэй) - их в строковых константах надо удваивать, например

     puts("a\\b");

выведет

     a\b

Comment: Так тоже не работает:

    std::regex exp("[A-Z][a-z]{1,20}\s[A-Z]\.\s[A-Z]\.");
    std::cout<<regex_match("Marty I. I.", exp);

добавлял слеши:

    std::regex exp("/[A-Z][a-z]{1,20}\s[A-Z]\.\s[A-Z]\./");
аналогично

Comment: @devnikor какой именно компилятор Вы используете? (версия и платформа).

Comment: @KoVadim
VS11, Win x64

Comment: Просто в g++ regex_match реализован очень просто - он возвращает false. всегда.
Для студии есть хорошая [статья](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/206330/Learning-REGEX-regular-expression-in-the-most-easi).

У меня нет сейчас 11 студии под боком, не могу проверить. Но думаю, Вам стоит попробовать с выражений:

    "[a-z]" и строки "t"
    "[a-z]+" и "trtrt"
    "[A-Za-z. ]+" и "Marty I. I."

Они должны "матчиться". И потом, по кусочкам, учиться.

Comment: Я попробовал выражение

       const char *exp = "(^[A-Z][a-z]*\\s+[A-Z]\\.\\s*[A-Z]\\.)"
        "|(^[A-Z][a-z]*-[A-Z][a-z]*\\s+[A-Z]\\.\\s*[A-Z]\\.)"
        "|(^[А-Я][а-я]*\\s+[А-Я]\\.\\s*[А-Я]\\.)"
        "|(^[А-Я][а-я]*-[А-Я][а-я]*\\s+[А-Я]\\.\\s*[А-Я]\\.)";

и в С++ получаю `catch exception` в

          regex e(exp);
      
       ...
       g++ regex.cpp -std=c++0x

А вот в Си `regcomp()/regexec()` (тот же g++ !!!) все (как и ожидалось) замечательно работает (и с Петров-Водкин К.С. в UTF-8 тоже), только setlocale() в начале программы нужен.

--

Кто-нибудь может объяснить, почему???

Comment: Похоже [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12910626) немного прояснили.

    According to the gcc implementation status (ver 4.6.3) the regex library is not yet completely implemented. It throws no errors and provides no warnings. Which is unpleasant, indeed.

Еще один камешек по крестам, хотя у меня-то как раз *throws error*.

Comment: А где же Ё и дефисы?